# Undefined array key "product" laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
[{"id":1,"created_at":"2022-08-31 23:12:48","updated_at":"2022-08-24 23:12:48","deleted_at":null,"product_id":1,"user_id":1,"product":{"id":1,"product_name":"android","product_desc":"android Product Desc","product_tag":"android  Product Tag","price":"52.00","available_stock":1,"active":1,"created_at":"2022-08-21 17:39:31","updated_at":"2022-08-22 13:53:51","deleted_at":null},"user":{"id":1,"name":"test@gmail.com","email":"test@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"created_at":"2022-08-21 17:40:21","updated_at":"2022-08-21 17:40:21","deleted_at":null}}]
```

```
^ Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1643 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => App\Models\Wishlist {#1645 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      +table: "wishlists"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #withCount: []
      +preventsLazyLoading: false
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▶]
      #original: array:6 [▶]
      #changes: []
      #casts: array:1 [▶]
      #classCastCache: []
      #attributeCastCache: []
      #dates: array:3 [▶]
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #dispatchesEvents: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:2 [▼
        "product" => App\Models\Product {#1631 ▼
          #connection: "mysql"
          +table: "products"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          +preventsLazyLoading: false
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
          #attributes: array:10 [▶]
          #original: array:10 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: array:1 [▶]
          #classCastCache: []
          #attributeCastCache: []
          #dates: array:3 [▶]
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: []
          #visible: []
          #fillable: array:9 [▶]
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #forceDeleting: false
        }
        "user" => App\Models\User {#1628 ▼
          #connection: "mysql"
          +table: "users"
          #primaryKey: "id"
          #keyType: "int"
          +incrementing: true
          #with: []
          #withCount: []
          +preventsLazyLoading: false
          #perPage: 15
          +exists: true
          +wasRecentlyCreated: false
          #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
          #attributes: array:9 [▶]
          #original: array:9 [▶]
          #changes: []
          #casts: array:1 [▶]
          #classCastCache: []
          #attributeCastCache: []
          #dates: array:4 [▶]
          #dateFormat: null
          #appends: []
          #dispatchesEvents: []
          #observables: []
          #relations: []
          #touches: []
          +timestamps: true
          #hidden: array:2 [▶]
          #visible: []
          #fillable: array:8 [▶]
          #guarded: array:1 [▶]
          #rememberTokenName: "remember_token"
          #forceDeleting: false
        }
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #fillable: array:5 [▼
        0 => "product_id"
        1 => "user_id"
        2 => "created_at"
        3 => "updated_at"
        4 => "deleted_at"
      ]
      #guarded: array:1 [▼
        0 => "*"
      ]
      #forceDeleting: false
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

```
 $product->update($request->all());
        $wishlists =Wishlist::with(['product', 'user'])->find($product);
  
     
           
                $userSchema=$wishlists['product']->price;
                return json_decode($userSchema);
```

here wishlists get 3 table i want to get product price how?

here wishlists get 3 table i want to get product price how?here wishlists get 3 table i want to get product price how?here wishlists get 3 table i want to get product price how?here wishlists get 3 table i want to get product price how?here wishlists get 3 table i want to get product price how?here wishlists get 3 table i want to get product price how?

Comment: Is the first line the output of `dd($wishlists)` from the code snippet you shared? It doesn't look correct

Answer (score 1):

Try `$wishlists->product->price` to get the price. Your result is probably a model, not an associative array in order to access properties using the `$wishlists['product']` syntax.

If `$wishlists` is a collection (more than 1 result), you need to loop through it and extract the price:

```
foreach($wishlists as $wishlist){
   $price = $wishlist->price;
   // do whatever you want with the price...
}
```

Comment: Property [product] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: $wishlists is a collection, which means you have more than one object. You need to loop through the collection in order to access the property (for example, `foreach($wishlists as $wishlist) { dd($wishlist->product->price); }`). If you only need one result, use `->first();` when retreiving the wishlists.

Comment: yep, $wishlists look like a collection if on the controller side you call get() it will return multiple results and need to foreach. if you call first() then it will be a single result.